# artifactory classifier metadata snapshot maven 3.0

Tags: maven, classification, artifactory, maven-metadata

My problem is "simple" but I didn´t found the solution until now:

I have 2 projects.

- Project A **built** with a **classifier** (called dev or pro) with help of a specific profile
- Project B with a **dependency** to A (using classifier dev or pro)
- I execute **install goal on A** with a classifier (**dev**)
- I **re-execute** install goal with another classifier (**pro**)

Then I compile the B project 
(and i put the dependency to A, with classifier DEV)

**It works well.**

---

But when I do the same with **artifactory** (goal deploy) , **it doesn´t work**
(and the repository is configured "unique")

It doesn´t work because artifactory? maven dependency? **is trying to download
A with classifier dev *AND* latest timestamp, buildnumber of whatever**.

But this "logic" is wrong because the latest timestamp is valid for A classifier pro!!!

I read the metadata.xml between local repository and artifactory repository. There are similar (but not exactly the same)

What i´m wrong? 
Thanks guys!

- Maven version : 3.03
- Artifactory version : 2.3.4.1

Answer (score 5):

This might be due to the fact that at the time of writing this answer, Artifactory generates Maven 2 type of metadata, which as opposed to the newer type generated by Maven 3, does not specify a separate "latest version" per classifier\type of Artifact.

That is, while Maven 2 metadata specifies the latest build and known history:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <metadata>
      <groupId>org.jfrog.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>multi1</artifactId>
      <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <versioning>
        <snapshot>
          <timestamp>20110928.112713</timestamp>
          <buildNumber>14</buildNumber>
        </snapshot>
        <lastUpdated>20110928112718</lastUpdated>
      </versioning>
    </metadata>
```

Maven 3 specifies the latest build per artifact type and classifier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.jfrog.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>multi1</artifactId>
  <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20110928.112713</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>14</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20110928112718</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>2.1-20110928.112713-14</value>
        <updated>20110928112713</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>2.1-20110928.112713-14</value>
        <updated>20110928112713</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      ...
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Support for Maven 3 metadata generation is currently [planned](https://issues.jfrog.org/jira/browse/RTFACT-3794) for Artifactory's next version (2.3.5).
Until then I can only suggest that you produce both artifacts with different artifact IDs.

Comment: I will wait the next version of artifactory. It was not easy to understand the relation between RTFACT-3794 and this problem (for me, of course).